# Find the value of $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln x}\right)^{\ln\left(x^2+x\right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

So this is my attempt to the question:

Let,

$$y=\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln x}\right)^{\ln\left(x^2+x\right)}$$
$$\ln y=\ln(x^2+x)\ln\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln x}\right)$$

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\ln y=\lim _{x\to \infty }\ln(x^2+x)\ln\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln x}\right)$$

Solving for the right side, since it is in the form of $\infty\cdot0$, we can change this into

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{\ln(x^2+x)}{\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln x}\right)}}$$

So that we can then use the L'Hopital rule.

However, after using the L'Hopital rule once, I found the form to be even more complicated and still becomes an indeterminate form.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe that,

$$
\begin{align}\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln x}\right)^{\ln\left(x^2+x\right)}=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln x}\right)^{\frac {\ln x}{4}}\right)^{\frac {4\ln (x^2+x)}{\ln x}}\end{align}
$$

Since $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln x}\right)^{\frac {\ln x}{4}}=e$, we need to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac {\ln (x^2+x)}{\ln x}.$$

Using the following inequality

$$
\begin{align}2=\frac {\ln (x^2)}{\ln x}≤\frac {\ln (x^2+x)}{\ln x}≤\frac {\ln (x^2+x^2)}{\ln x}=2+\frac {\ln 2}{\ln x}\end{align}
$$

and applying the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) we have:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac {\ln (x^2+x)}{\ln x}=2.$$

Thus, we conclude:

$$\begin{align}\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln x}\right)^{\ln\left(x^2+x\right)}&=e^{4\cdot 2}\\
&=e^8.\end{align}$$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac {\ln (x^2+x)}{\ln x}$ can also be solved using L'Hôpital's rule easily.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac {\ln (x^2+x)}{\ln x} = \lim_{x\to\infty }\frac {\ln(x) +\ln(x+1)}{\ln x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} 1 + \frac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln(x)} = \lim_{x\to \infty} 1 + \frac{\frac{1}{x+1}}{\frac{1}{x}} = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

$L=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln{x}}\right)^{\ln{(x^2+x)}}=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln{x}}\right)^{\ln{x}}\left(1+\frac{4}{\ln{x}}\right)^{\ln{(x+1)}}$

Let $y=\ln{x}$.

$L=\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{4}{y}\right)^y \left(\left(1+\frac{4}{y}\right)^y\right)^{\ln{(x+1)}/\ln{x}}=e^4\left(e^4\right)^1=e^8$

Comment: Why can we directly evaluate $ln(x+1)/lnx$ into 1 here, although the limit is for $y\rightarrow\infty$ rather than $x\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: $y=\ln{x}$, so $x\to\infty$ as $y\to\infty$. Then $\ln{(x+1)}/\ln{x}\to1$ by L'Hopital's rule.